# Convert numeric to date

Tags: r, type-conversion

I'd like to convert this type of numeric values to a date but it doesn't work.

`20100727` for instance

I tried to convert the numeric to character and applied this :

```
as.Date("20100727", "Y%d%m")
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were setting wrong order of month and date values (in your code was Year, Date, Month, should be Year, Month, Date).

```
as.Date("20100727", "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2010-07-27"
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a numeric value, `20100727`, `as.Date` requires it to be first converted to string, or else, would have issue

```
as.Date(20100727, "%Y%m%d")
```

> Error in charToDate(x) :    character string is not in a standard
>   unambiguous format

---

`anydate` from `anytime` can internally do this conversion

```
library(anytime)
date1 <- anydate(20100727)
date1
#[1] "2010-07-27"
str(date1)
#Date[1:1], format: "2010-07-27"
```

Also, takes the character string as input

```
anydate("20100727")
#[1] "2010-07-27"
```