# converting numeric variable into Date format in R

Tags: r

I m working on a data set where there is a numeric variable.

I want to convert it into date format and tried calling `as.Date` but it didn't work.

```
  crn_n    P_1         dec CRNDate
1 35911497 0.1329592   1   18673
2 47337031 0.1253279   1   19110
3 80686894 0.1183780   1   20010
4 31359775 0.1183780   1   18443
5 31149712 0.1176850   1   18434
6 83745145 0.1142335   1   20102
```

How to convert `CRNDate` into Date format

Comment: can you show us the code your tried so we can help you

Comment: Also can you provide some sample data in a copy-paste friendly way, for example by giving us the output of `dput(head(your_data))`. What you gave is quite un-readable at the moment.

Comment: Did you read through `?as.Date`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert numeric to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148624/convert-numeric-to-date) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144343/converting-numeric-to-date-issues

Comment: @antoine-sac, it's not that difficult to read in fact. Just the initial formatting was bad

Comment: I don't understand how is your CRNDate column formatted? What does the integer means? `18673`, `19110` are obviouly not timestamps

Comment: @Eloims, I suspect it's the number of days from some origin

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague, but here's a wild guess:

#### Assumptions:

- number indicates time passed since an origin
- time passed is in days.

#### Define your origin:

```
start = as.Date("1900-01-01")
```

#### Get dates

```
df$date = as.Date(df$CRNDate, origin=start)
```